# Algorithm or Open Source implementation for custom Auto-Focus

Tags: java, c, algorithm, open-source, autofocus

I've noticed that in some devices without true optical focus control, (Blackberries, Android phones, etc), there's a built-in digital auto-focus mechanism.

I suppouse that this mechanism is fully implemented in software, applying an image "sharping" algorithm to the images feed by the camera)*.

Is there an algorithm (or even an open source library in Java or C) so that I can apply it to an image after it has been captured?

Thanks in advance.

*UPDATE: Seems that what I'm looking for is not actually auto-focus, since it involves detecting the best focus level and a mean to change it via API. What I need is an algorithm that given a blurred input image, produces an output image with better definition.

Comment: I'd say focusing in cameras is a different thing than any sharpening algorithm. Allthough OT then, referring focusing approaches this might be of interest: http://www.doc.com/technologies/Documents/Lens%20Tilt%20in%20Miniature%20AF%20Cameras.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. And agree, I'll update my question with a better description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're about deconvolution. Say, we have convolution g(x)a = h where g is an original image, a - camera aperture and h - sensed ('blurred') image, (x) - convolution operation.

Deconvolution is computing G with known A and H, and can be done in many ways.

One is based on fact that Fg(i) * Fa(i) = Fh(i), where F is fourier transform. Obviously Fg(i) = Fh(i) / Fa(i).

In practice, deconvolution greatly increases noise so there's need in noise suppressing algorithm to use with.